# Typescript for parsed data - geojson

Tags: typescript, casting, typescript-namespace

I have a simple typescript app using vite that is supposed to rad a geojson and display it as a map. Simple enough, but as I'm not extremely proficient with typescript, I ran into a problem:

```js
//importing the file as a string, I declared a module that types it correctly
import worldGeoJson from '@/assets/world.geojson?raw'

const worldJson = JSON.parse(worldGeoJson)
```

Now, the problem I ran into is that worldJson has now type `any`. So, I installed `@types/geojson` and tried to simply assign it like:

```js
const worldJson: GeoJSON = JSON.parse(worldGeoJson)
```

but now I'm getting a message of `Cannot use namespace 'GeoJSON' as a type.` - fair enough, but I have failed in my attempts of casting it into a type. I guess I could import all types inside geojson type file and reconstruct it myself but I have a feeling it would defeat the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Most probably you have a FeatureCollection, but without seeing your actual data (or at least a sample), it is just a wild guess.

Comment: Yes, I do, I could further in my code use something like `import @types/geojson; (...) worldJson.features as FeatureCollection` but that wouldn't fix the underlying problem of me not understanding how to properly use modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also import types, including named exported types, in the same manner as usual JS modules:

```
// Import the named export "FeatureCollection" from @types/geojson
import type { FeatureCollection } from "geojson";

// JSON.parse has no way to know the resulting type,
// so we have to specify it with a type assertion
const worldJson = JSON.parse("string GeoJSON FeatureCollection") as FeatureCollection;
//    ^? FeatureCollection<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>

// Then we can safely use the object
worldJson.features; // Okay
//        ^? Feature<Geometry, GeoJsonProperties>[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkFsAcHsCcAupEAsCmoB2BDS6ATUdADziVACIAxdHRAV3nQGFYAbd9AY0QEtYWSqABm8WJFAABRAE9o6AM7AA5ulgArRYIBQfGAmRyFoAN6ha9Jqw5deArKAC+o8ZMprN2oQG4dOkFAAKQBlAHkAOQA6aBx4RUxUHEVsWFAAdxxZFDSAayxYdJQMUGZFBnZ+LBUUeXQAGgCwbQzEnAA3TEQ0xQVuPhFsvmR04dRQHFqTZISkBx1uQUURhHYCIO9QAF5g8OjY+PQACkpl+D5q0ABxdVDIizpGZjZOHn5BSgBKCZTLJ5tXvZBH5AqAwQA9AD8-kCABUMI50phuDhHIocCJ0OxsgwEsVMLAAEYaN46dKrdbeKKYqxlHygQJhXJZJpgtlsqE6IA)